# Upload de arquivos usando ASP.NET MVC, AJAX e jQuery

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com o seguinte problema quando faço o upload de arquivo para no ASP.NET MVC com AJAX e jQuery

ele entra no if que verifica se ListaArquivos != null

e chega em Console.WriteLine(source.FileName); pra imprimir o nome do arquivo no terminal

Minha divida e a seguinte se meu ajax esta erado? ou tem erro no controlador, porque esta da erro na variável documento na hora que leva ela pra função que conta os caracteres do arquivo enviado

```html
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<FormularioPrincipalViewModel> LerArquivo([FromForm]FormularioPrincipalViewModel model)//IList<IFormFile> arquivos
        {
            int totalDeCaracteres = 0;
            int quantidadeDeCaracteres = 0;
           //var documentos = new List<Documento>();  //Inutil por enquanto


            if (model.ListaArquivos != null)
            {
                foreach (IFormFile source in model.ListaArquivos)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(source.FileName);
                    using MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                    if (Models.Configuration.Documento.ValidarImagem(source.ContentType))
                    {
                        source.CopyTo(output);
                        quantidadeDeCaracteres = leitorDeImagem.Executar(output);
                        totalDeCaracteres += quantidadeDeCaracteres;
                    }


                    if (Models.Configuration.Documento.ValidarPdf(source.ContentType))
                    {
                        source.CopyTo(output);
                        quantidadeDeCaracteres = leitorDePdf.Executar(source.FileName, output);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("O Total de caracteres é {0}.", quantidadeDeCaracteres);
                        totalDeCaracteres += quantidadeDeCaracteres;
                    }


                    var documento = new Documento(source.ContentType, output.ToArray(), quantidadeDeCaracteres);

                    model.Orcamento.AdicionarDocumento(documento);
                    //documentos.Add(documento);
                    await documentoRepositorio.Adicionar(documento);//----------------------------------------------------------

                }
                

                model.QuantidadeDeCaracteres = totalDeCaracteres;
                Console.WriteLine(model.ListaArquivos.Count());
                Console.WriteLine(model.QuantidadeDeCaracteres);

            }
            return model;
        }
```

```js
    var formdata = new FormData($('#arquivo').get(0));

    $("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            data: formdata, // $('#formlist').serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Orcamento/AdicionarDocumento',
            success: function () {
              
                

            }

        })
    })
```

Comment: Qual erro? Em qual linha? Coloque o erro aqui que facilita bastante...